# Can I create an adhoc parameterized DAG from scheduler job DAG running once a minute

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm researching Airflow to see if it is a viable fit for my use case and not clear from the documentation if it fits this scenario. I'd like to schedule a job workflow per customer based on some very dynamic criteria which doesn't fall into the standard "CRON" loop of running every X minutes etc. (since there is some impact of running together)

Customer DB

```
Customer_id, "CRON" desired interval (best case)
1 , 30 minutes
2 , 2 hours
...
... <<<<<<< thousands of these potential jobs
```

Every minute I'd like to query the state of the current work in the system as well as real world "sensor" data which changes often (such as load on some DBs, or quotas to other resources, or adhoc priorities, boosting etc.)

When decided, I'd need to create a "DAG" (pipeline) of work per customer which had been deemed worthy of running at this time (since perhaps we want to delay work for the "CRON" given some complicated analysis).

For instance :

Every minute run this test:

```
for customer in DB:
  if (shouldRunDAGForCustomer(customer)):
     Create a DAG with states ..... and run it
"Sleep for a minute"

def shouldRunDagForCustomer(...):
   currentStateOfJobs = ....
   situationalAwarenessOfWorld = .... // check all sort of interesting metrics
   if some criteria is met for this customer: return true // run the dag for this customer
   else : return false
```

From the material I've read, it seems that the Dags are given a specifed schedule and are static in their structure. Also seems that DAGs run on all their inputs, not generated per input. 
Also wasn't clear on how the scheduling works, if the given DAG hadn't completed but the schedule time had arrived. Would I have potentially multiple runs of the same pipeline for the same input (Bad). As I have pipelines whose time to complete varies depending on customer, dynamic load of system etc. I'd like to manage the scheduling aspect myself and generation of "DAG"

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through a "controller" DAG that is scheduled every minute, which then triggers runs for a "target" DAG when desired conditions are met. Airflow has a good example of this, see [example_trigger_controller_dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_controller_dag.py) and [example_trigger_target_dag](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_trigger_target_dag.py). The controller uses the `TriggerDagRunOperator()` which is an operator that kicks off a run for any desired DAG.

```
trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id="test_trigger_dagrun",
    trigger_dag_id="example_trigger_target_dag",  # Ensure this equals the dag_id of the DAG to trigger
    conf={"message": "Hello World"},
    dag=dag,
)
```

Then the target DAG doesn't need to do anything special except should have `schedule_interval=None`. Note that on trigger, you can populate a `conf` dictionary that the target can later consume, in case you want to customize each triggered run.

```
bash_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="bash_task",
    bash_command='echo "Here is the message: \'{{ dag_run.conf["message"] if dag_run else "" }}\'"',
    dag=dag,
)
```

Back to your case, your scenario is similar, but where you differ from the example is you won't kick off a DAG every time and you have multiple target DAGs that you could kick off. This is where the [ShortCircuitOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python_operator/index.html#airflow.operators.python_operator.ShortCircuitOperator) comes into play, which basically is a task that runs a python method you specify, which just needs to return true or false. If it returns true, then it continues onto the next downstream task as usual, otherwise it "short circuits" and stops skips the downstream task. Worth giving [example_short_circuit_operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_short_circuit_operator.py) a run if you want to see this demonstrated. With that and dynamic creation of tasks with a for-loop, I think you'll get something like this in your controller DAG:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='controller_customer_pipeline',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval='* * * * *',
)

def shouldRunDagForCustomer(customer, ...):
   currentStateOfJobs = ....
   situationalAwarenessOfWorld = .... // check all sort of interesting metrics
   if some criteria is met for this customer: return true // run the dag for this customer
   else : return false

for customer in DB:
   check_run_conditions = ShortCircuitOperator(
      task_id='check_run_conditions_' + customer,
      python_callable=shouldRunDagForCustomer,
      op_args=[customer],
      op_kwargs={...}, # extra params if needed
      dag=dag,
   )

   trigger_run = TriggerDagRunOperator(
      task_id='trigger_run_' + customer,
      trigger_dag_id='target_customer_pipeline_' + customer,  # standardize on DAG ids for per customer DAGs
      conf={"foo": "bar"},  # pass on extra info to triggered DAG if needed
      dag=dag,
   )

   check_run_conditions >> trigger_run
```

Then your target DAG is just the per customer work.

This is probably not the only way you could implement something like this, but basically yes I think it's viable to implement in Airflow.